# Web Scrape to List to CSV in Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to scrape a list of names and votes from a public voting record site for a large school in my area.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv 

poll_page = 'xurl.com'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(poll_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('div',attrs={'class': 'xyz'})
#nametest = name_box.text
name = name_box.text.splitlines()



with open('index.csv','w', newline='') as csv_file:
    thewriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    thewriter.writerow(['Name','Vote'])
    thewriter.writerow(name)
```

if I don't convert this to a list, `name=name_box.text` spits out those names like this:

```
Clark, Yes
Bob, No
Amanda, Yes
```

When I convert to a list name spits out the output:

```
['Clark, Yes' , 'Bob, No' , 'Amanda, Yes']
```

In my CSV I would like the name to be column A and the vote to be column B. I can't figure out to parse this correctly into a writerow. I can separate each out into a seperate array but I need to make sure each name is corresponding with the correct vote.

EDIT: I was able to write each name and vote on a new row using:

`with open('index.csv','w', newline='') as csv_file:
    thewriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    thewriter.writerow(['Name','Vote'])
    for item in name:
        thewriter.writerow([item,'x'])`

However, the next step is to separate the columns by a comma but then jump to a new row for a new name. Again my name list goes like this ['Clark, Yes', Bob, No'] and in the outputted csv I see:

```
Column A:
Row1: Clark, Yes
Row2: Bob, No
```

But I need the yes and no's to be in Column B while keeping the consistency of who voted for what. Any ideas of how to do this. Essentially I need to separate the list by commas but then jump to a new row.

Comment: looks like that `div` already contains CSV formatted data, why not just write that directly to the file?

Comment: You have to use `.writerows(<list>)`, note the ending `'s'`.

Comment: `thewriter.writerows([[y.strip() for y in x.split(',')] for x in name_box.text.splitlines()])` ...

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your list to a 2d list by splitting each string element by the comma delimiter. Then write it to file row by row. For example

```
names = ['Clark, Yes' , 'Bob, No' , 'Amanda, Yes'] # This is your current output from the scraper
names =  [name.split(',') for name in names]
with open('index.csv','w', newline='') as csv_file:
    thewriter = csv.writer(csv_file)
    thewriter.writerow(['Name','Vote'])
    for name in names:
        thewriter.writerow(name)
```